# GroupBy en nodejs mysql

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs

no se como hacer la consulta, siendo mas especifico no se como poner el group by en mi consulta, aqui va mi codigo

`objBD.query('SELECT u.ID_U, u.nombre, t.ID_T,t.tiempo, t.iteracion from USUARIO u  INNER JOIN TIEMPOS t ON u.ID_U=t.ID_U GROUP BY iteracion where u.ID_U=?',[i], function(err, rows, fields) {`

nota: sin el GROUP BY mi consulta funciona bien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` va al final de la consulta. Proba escribiendo `...WHERE u.ID_U=? GROUP BY t.iteraciones`